# Detect phone connection type from watch

Tags: android, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I have an Android watch that can be in one of the following:

```
1a. standalone - connected to a WiFi network directly;  
1b. standalone - connected via a cellular link (if SIM present, unlocked, etc.);  
2.  bluetooth connected to a phone and using the phone's connection (WiFi/cellular);
```

It can also be that both the watch and the phone have a SIM (though this is less important).

On the watch I run a standalone app (no counterpart app/service on the phone) and I need to find the 'end' connection type I have *when tethering*. Namely, *using the watch only*, I need to know if I am tethering via a WiFi or via a cellular connection.

Or, in other words, *when tethering*, I need to know if the phone (to which the watch is connected via bluetooth) sends my data further using WiFi or a cellular connection.

I did look around for a solution but what I found only allows identifying the type of connection the watch has, e.g. WiFi, cellular or bluetooth.

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance for your help!